# CSS animation svg shape not centered

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm trying to have the #oval-stroke element pulse outwards from the center of #first-oval but it keeps moving from the top left to the bottom right. Any ideas why this might be? I have the position set to relative with a left and top set to 0.

```css
    #first-oval {
   stroke-width: 2px;
   stroke-opacity: 1;
    }

 #oval-stroke {
   position: relative;
   top: 0%;
   left: 0%;
   fill: white;
   fill-opacity: 0;
    animation: pulse 4s forwards infinite;
 }

 @keyframes pulse {
   from {
     stroke-opacity: 1;
     transform: scale(0.5);
   }
   to {
     stroke-width: 0;
     stroke-opacity: 0;
     transform: scale(2);
   }
 }
```

```html
    <svg width="300" height="300" class="svgExample" expanded="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle id="first-oval" fill="red" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="92.5" cy="73.5" r="8.5" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"></circle>
      <circle id="oval-stroke" fill="red" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="92.5" cy="73.5" r="8.5" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round"></circle>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this to your #oval-stroke:

```css
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform-box: fill-box;
```

`transform-origin: 50% 50%;` means that the transformation should happen around the center of the element.

However some browsers take the center of the SVG canvas as the origin of the transformation. To fix this problem I add `transform-box: fill-box;`

```css
 #first-oval {
   stroke-width: 2px;
   stroke-opacity: 1;
    }

 #oval-stroke {
   position: relative;
   top: 0%;
   left: 0%;
   fill: white;
   fill-opacity: 0;
    /*************************/
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    /*************************/
    animation: pulse 4s forwards infinite;
 }

 @keyframes pulse {
   from {
     stroke-opacity: 1;
     transform: scale(0.5);
   }
   to {
     stroke-width: 0;
     stroke-opacity: 0;
     transform: scale(2);
   }
 }
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" class="svgExample" expanded="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle id="first-oval" fill="red" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="92.5" cy="73.5" r="8.5" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"></circle>
      <circle id="oval-stroke" fill="red" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="92.5" cy="73.5" r="8.5" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round"></circle>
    </svg>
```